# React.memo prevent rendering redux nested data doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am designing a messenger application on reactnative.

I have my redux store structured like this  :

[image: store structuration]

And this is my component which render :

[image: code component]

When an event is added in store with my reducer, all of messages components are rendered each times even if React.memo equalTo return true.

[image: reducer]

Result :

[image: result]

Expected result :

**Rendering only 1 time each MessageItem component (React.memo actually doesn't work, rendering even if propsEqualTo is true)**

Comment: As an unrelated side note: you should _really_ be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux), which will _drastically_ simplify the Redux logic you've shown there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry for that, I just found the solution after 6h research and post here ...

My React.memo component was rendering everytimes because I used a useSelector in it.
I removed and now it's OK.